# Muon-electron mass ratio

Tags: standard-model, quantum-electrodynamics, elementary-particles

I was watching [this video about The Standard Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eynBfTF7Gb4) and at 24:56, Michael Peskin said that Feynman tried to explain the ratio of muon to electron mass by doing some QED calculations and within an hour he got the answer. Is there any material on how he tried to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding , he says that it has not really been explained.

He calls it a "story" that Feynman calculated it, not a paper, and then realized that the explanation was not solid? it was a type of numerology with QED diagrams?

If you look at the Feynman lectures, Feynman [himself says the  ratio is not understood.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html) (paragraph 28.5)

> There is another particle in the world called a muon which, so far as we can tell, differs in no way whatsoever from an electron except for its mass. It acts in every way like an electron: it interacts with neutrinos and with the electromagnetic field, and it has no nuclear forces. It does nothing different from what an electron does—at least, nothing which cannot be understood as merely a consequence of its higher mass (206.77 times the electron mass). Therefore, whenever someone finally gets the explanation of the mass of an electron, he will then have the puzzle of where a muon gets its mass.

There are people working on this beyond the standard model , as in string theories , [for example](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9206083). As the particles in string theories are excitations of the fundamental string [the masses will be fitted](http://particle.physics.ucdavis.edu/seminars/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=2007:apr:kane-colloq.pdf) to the final string standard model , if/when it appears.